# Is "Let $M$ is a connected n-manifold, then: $M$ is $R$-orientable iff $H_n(M;R)\cong R$" true?

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, homology-cohomology, orientation

I heard that every topological $n$-manifold $M$ is $\mathbb{F}_2$-orientable, but then for $M=\mathbb{R}^2$ is must be $H_2(\mathbb{R}^2;\mathbb{F}_2)\neq 0$?

In lecture we had the lemma: Let $M$ is a connected n-manifold, then: $M$ is $R$-orientable iff $H_n(M;R)\cong R$.

Something must be wrong, I always thought that $H_2(\mathbb{R}^2;\mathbb{F}_2)=0$ because $M$ is contractible. Or is the lemma only true for compact manifolds?

Comment: There is a statement for non-compact manifolds, but you will need to use something like compactly supported cohomology. I believe this is also in Hatcher.

Comment: good to know, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is true only for compact manifolds (I assume that your "manifolds" are not allowed to have boundary).  In fact, $H_n(M;R)\cong R$ iff $M$ is $R$-orientable *and* compact.  You should be able to find a proof in any text that covers Poincaré duality.  For instance, this follows from Theorem 3.26 and Proposition 3.29 of [Hatcher's *Algebraic Topology*](https://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/ATchapters.html) (note the hypothesis that $M$ is closed in Theorem 3.26).